# Stable Marriage Problem

Tags: graph-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

I would just like clarification for the following problem: Suppose $M_1$ and $M_2$ are two stable matchings between n men and n women, and we allow each woman to choose between the man she is paired with in $M_1$ and the partner she receives in $M_2$.  Each woman always chooses the man she prefers.  Show that the result is a stable matching between the men and the women.

**Clarification:** I understand what it means to be a stable marriage. However, I do not know what exactly $M_1$ and $M_2$ are. Are they just the two different lists each man and woman provides, which order their preferences for each man and each woman? Furthermore, what are the differences between the words "paired" and "received" as it pertains to this problem? I appreciate the input.

Comment: I think that the difference between "paired" and "received" is none, this looks like a particularily awkward case of elegant variation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elegant_variation) which is unfortunate since the problem writer should aim for clarity. Your problem is interesting but I could not solve it.

Comment: @Sid Haha, I laughed when I read the first sentence of your link. Do you by any chance know the difference between M1 and M2?

Comment: $M_1$ and $M_2$ are just two stable matchings of some bipartite graph when the nodes are men and women. Using those two matchings, we create a third matching (which we can call $M_3$) by allowing each woman to select the man she was paired with in $M_1$ and $M_2$ that is higher on her preference list. We are to show that $M_3$ is also a stable matching, which is not trivial. I solved a few similar problems when I took a course in graph theory; try to assure yourself that the statement is true by attempting to create counterexamples, then look for some pattern which can help you create a proof.

Comment: @Sid Right on man. I appreciate it.